# BEPUphysics collision with generated terrain?

Tags: xna, physics

I've got randomly generated terrain which is stored in a indices and vertex buffer.  How do I go about using this for collision in BEPU?  It seems I can do it with a Mesh but it would be a waste to convert it to a Mesh :/.

Comment: did you found answer? I'm having same problem

Answer (score 1):

If it is a traditional terrain (i.e. generated from a heightmap), all you need to do is pass the constructor for BepuPhysics.Collidable.Terrain an array of heights, then provide a world matrix.
If your "terrain" allows for concaves, then you will need to use a Mesh.